# How to add GPS points from a CSV/Excel file to a QGIS project?

Tags: qgis, point, gps, csv, mapping

I thought I knew QGIS quite a bit by now, but a straight forward simple task recently brought me close to frustration. I had collected the GPS coordinates of points using my cellphone in an Excel spreadsheet and wanted to add these points to a QGIS project.

The Excel spreadsheet exported as a .csv file looks like this:

```
Name;X;Y
Pole 1;32,56277;-2,572113
Pole 2;39,3216;-1,523516
```

I added a Delimited Text Layer and chose the .csv file but nothing showed up on the map.

I am using QGIS 3.10

Comment: Its very similar yes, thank you for sharing.  It was hard for me to find this answer however, because part of the answer is in Italian. Thats why I posted this question for english speaking users.

Answer (score 2):

The first step was to make sure that the .csv file is formatted in a way QGIS recognizes the numbers as numbers and not as a text. The comma (,) decimal separator was not recognized by QGIS. I had to make sure that the .csv file used a dot (.) as a decimal separator. In my case I just used a text editor to replace all commas by dots.

The .csv file then looked like that:

```
Name;X;Y
Pole 1;32.56277;-2.572113
Pole 2;39.3216;-1.523516
```

> EDIT: As suggested by Erik: There is a checkbox "Decimal Separator is comma" that when checked recognizes the numbers without fiddling in a text editor.

Then I had to go to Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Delimited Text Layer:

[image: Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Delimited Text Layer]

I used the following settings in the dialogue:

[image: ![Settings for Delimited Text Layer]

To add the points to the map you need to click Add.

In my case the points now finally showed up, however at a wrong location.
This happened because I had mistakenly swapped the X and Y coordinate in my .csv file.
So I had to change the two columns in the Add Delimited Text Layer Menu from X Field: X and Y Field: Y to X Field: Y and Y Field: X
Then the points showed up at the right location.

[image: Changed order of X and Y coordinates]

Hope this helps someone stuck with the same problem.

Comment: If you click the correct checkbox, QGIS recognizes comma for decimal separators.

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html?highlight=load%20csv#records-and-fields

Comment: Yes thank you the checkbox "Decimal separator is comma" also works

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favour and install the fantastic spreadsheet layers plugin (more infos here: https://github.com/camptocamp/QGIS-SpreadSheetLayers)

1. After installation you can easily import excel-spreadsheets:
   [image]
2. Dont forget to set the appropriate Geometry columns for lat and lon:
   [image]
3. you are done!